# Join three variables and later extract with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am joining together 3 variables into a filename seperated by a `--` for use in another Cloud function. I do this with the following code below:

`const newFileName = size + "--" + bytes + "--" +  name + ".txt";`

How can I seperate these later with Regex?

size (extract before first --)

bytes (extract after first --)

name (extract after second --)

Comment: Not using regex but plain string methods might be simpler here - especially if you don't [know regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: Does `name` include `.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always use the same extension `.txt` you might remove that part from the string and then split on `--`

```js
let str = "aaa--bbb--ccc.txt";
[size, bytes, name] = str.substring(0, str.length - 4).split("--");
console.log(size);
console.log(bytes);
console.log(name);
```

Another option could be to split on either `--` or on a pattern that would match the last dot followed by matching not a dot until the end of the string.

```js
let str = "aaa--bbb--ccc.txt";
[size, bytes, name] = str.split(/--|\.[^.]+$/);
console.log(size);
console.log(bytes);
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use this regex, it will pull the three parts into 3 different capture groups named "size", "bytes", and "name":

```
^(?<size>.*?)\-\-(?<bytes>.*?)\-\-(?<name>.*?[.txt])$
```

In javascript, you can use this code to pull the groups out afterwards:

```
var reg = /^(?<size>.*?)\-\-(?<bytes>.*?)\-\-(?<name>.*?[.txt])$/
var matches = "123--456--test.txt".match(reg);
var size = matches["groups"]["size"]
var bytes = matches["groups"]["bytes"]
var name = matches["groups"]["name"]
```

Where the "123--456--test.txt" string is instead the string you want to pull the data out of.

EDIT:

Like StackSlave pointed out, named capture groups like above are not always supported. If you need to support a browser or language that can't deal with named groups, you can instead do this:

```
var reg = /^(.*?)\-\-(.*?)\-\-(.*?)$/
var matches = "123--456--test.txt".match(reg);
var size = matches[1]
var bytes = matches[2]
var name = matches[3]
```

EDIT EDIT:

To get the file name without extension, use this regex instead:

```
var reg = /(.*?)\-\-(.*?)\-\-(.*?)\./
var matches = "123--456--test.txt".match(reg);
var size = matches[1]
var bytes = matches[2]
var name = matches[3]
```

Comment: Named pattern grouping is not widely supported, just use numeric groups.

Comment: Can we get the final part text without a file extension? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mZNomo?editors=1112

Comment: @StackSlave good point, thanks. Do you happen to know where support starts for it? I believe it's worked for me in a couple of IE10 projects, but not sure besides that.

Comment: @sigur7 the last example will match the name without the extension.

Comment: I don't know about support for named pattern matching that other than it's experimental. By the way... `(.*?)` would be ungreedy anything or nothing, so you'll get '' *(nothing but an empty string)*. If you just want pattern matching anything or nothing it's `(.*)`.

Comment: @StackSlave it greedy vs non-greedy doesn't matter in this case. You won't get nothing - it will just find the minumum number of matching characters as opposed to maximum with greedy, but it will still keep matching until it hits the next character (in this case, \.). If you run it against a test string in his format ('123--456--test.txt') you'll see you get the same results whether you use greedy or non-greedy. Honestly I'm mostly just used to using non-greedy, didn't bother to change it since it didn't matter for this.

Comment: With non-greedy, you could also just use this: (.*?)(--|\.) which would give each section as a different match. Wouldn't work with greedy though, since it would keep matching until the last '.'. Figured it would be easier to understand groups though.

Comment: `var m = '123--456--test.txt'.match(/(.*?)/);
console.log(m);` proves you are incorrect. You may want to test your code first.

Comment: @StackSlave Heck, run your example with just this and see what you get: console.log('123--456--test.txt'.match(/(.*?)\-\-/))

Comment: @StackSlave in case this helps with understanding: https://imgur.com/a/oOqXEsC. Also, Regex101 (https://regex101.com/) is a great place to test regex's out in the future.

Comment: That only works because entire expression matches first, then the parentheses are read and you have `\\.` after the last `(.*?)`. In other words, there is no reason for those ungreedy flags. If you were to put `(.*?)` at the end of the expression you will see that it will be an empty string at that index.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been saying - in this case, it makes no difference. I understand that there are times to use greedy, but in this case it does not matter, and I was originally writing it like /(.*?)(--|\.)/ which would require non-greedy in order to work. Since either greedy or non-greedy works in this case, there isn't any particular reason to use one over the other, so I see no point in changing it, or in calling the answer wrong when it uses one or the other. You specifically said that my regex would get "nothing but an empty string", which is objectively incorrect however.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a numeric example:

```js
var str = 'size--bytes--name.ext', m = str.match(/^(.+)--(.+)--(.+)(?:\..+)$/);
console.log(m); console.log('size:'+m[1]); console.log('bytes:'+m[2]); console.log('name:'+m[3]);
```

Comment: You've got too many sets of dashes. There isn't a double dash between name and extension. I also added a numeric example to mine.